# Custom Projection Definition - Excel Formula to ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, proj, affine-transformation

I have been given an Excel formula for converting a custom projection coordinate point to a known defined system (state plane AZ East)

I'm trying to get create a custom projection definition in ArcGIS Pro, or maybe even a Proj4 String although I am trying to use ArcGIS Pro for this.... To go back and forth between these 2 systems, and I don't understand what these constants are representing.

Easting Formula:

[image]

```
=(G3 x 0.999787146*0.999970725)-(H3 x 0.999787146*(-0.00765174))+469812.2449
```

Northing Formula:
[image]

```
=(G3 x 0.999787146*(-0.00765174))+(H3 x 0.999787146*0.999970725)+872132.9836
```

ArcGis Pro - New Coordinate System Information

[image]